# How can we block a single file but it should be viewable and uploadable?

Tags: windows, file-permissions

I need a help,

How can we block single file but it should be viewable and uploadable from one folder. We are generating some CSV file that file should not be editable, but it should be viewable and uploadable.

Or how can we stop save as function in a CSV file?

This all process should be get affect from a BAT file or from any .net pages (VB/C#)

Comment: Can you explain what the ultimate goal is here. It's difficult to understand what you are asking for at the moment.

Comment: Set the readonly flag on the file.

Comment: system generating one CSV file to shared folder, but this should not be modified by the user or any one from our network. but one user from our network he will just upload the CSV files to one of the bank site, and who is receving this file they should able to modify this file.

Answer (score 1):

As CBZ mentioned, make the files are read-only. That way the files cannot be edited, but cam be viewed.

Making it read-only also means that you cannot replace the file - btw.